# Conditional .OfType()?

Tags: c#, linq

suppose we have a base class A and 2 derived classes B & C.  if I wanted to query for instances of a certain type given as a string, how would I do it?

I'd like to write:

```
var q = A.OfType<t == "B" ? B : C>()
```

but that won't compile, and I don't really want to write two different queries:

```
var q;
if (t == "A") q = A.OfType<B>();
else q = A.OfType<C>();
```

suggestions anyone?

Comment: This isn't LINQ and my suggestion is if your second code snippet works, you should use it.

Comment: An alternative to `OfType<>` is `.Where(x => x is A)`

Comment: Generics do their magic at compile time, so of course option 1 will not work

Comment: What's wrong with the second option? It's probably the best way, altough I'd shorten it: `var q = t == "B" ? A.OfType<B>() : A.OfType<C>();`

Comment: What are you doing with the types `B` and `C`? `OfType` is usually used to get a strongly typed set.

Comment: @jods This won't work - different return types of ternary operator.

Comment: I am curious as to what type you'd like to be inferred for q.

Comment: @BartoszKP: right. But we could change the code to type it as `IEnumerable<A>` thanks to covariance, right?

Comment: And is OfType a static method of the type A? I cannot make sense of this question.

Comment: @EricLippert: probably the OP meant that `A` should be some instance of `IEnumerable<A>`? That's how I understood it.

Comment: you just need to know what type it is from a string?...like...result will be type A if string is "A"?

Comment: @jods Yes, but not the way you wrote it - it needs to be explicit for each part of the operator.

Comment: @EricLippert, well... I'd be happy to have it infer A

Comment: yes, sorry guys, A is actually a LINQ query

Comment: @Silvermind, I forget about `.Where(x => x is A)` - cool solution.  you get a point.  thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest thing I've came up with is:

```
var q = a.Where(e => (t == "B" && e is B) || (t != "B" && e is C));
```

Another possibility, partially suggested by jods in the comments:

```
var q = t == "B"
        ? ((IEnumerable<A>)a.OfType<B>())
        : ((IEnumerable<A>)a.OfType<C>());
```

However in both cases result will be of type `<A>` as you can't have a function's return type dependent on run time conditions, because it must be determined at compile time.

Comment: That's a possibility to avoid "writing two different queries", as the OP wrote it. Although I have to say that I see no benefit and this solution is only guaranteed to be slower.

Comment: @jods I agree, I also don't see any sense in this. Just a closest thing I got to what OP requested.

Comment: I guess the answer is there isn't some clever way in C# to deal with this. in that case, either of the two answers above seems like a reasonable path.  thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score -1):

Not exactly what you want, but the ternary operator (?:) is a beautiful thing,

```
var q = (t=="B") ? A.OfType<B>() : A.OfType<C>() ;
```

(see [How to use ternary operator for this statement in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678311/how-to-use-ternary-operator-for-this-statement-in-c-sharp))

Comment: There is no implicit conversion between... etc.

Comment: This won't compile - ternary operator must return the same type in both cases.

Comment: you could typecast the error away but you are still technically doing two queries here.