# How to use inline c# if instead of using long c# if statement

Tags: c#, if-statement

How to use single line if statement that reduce the number of lines of code for these kind of coding

```
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtpictext.Text))
        {
            Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pictext", DBNull.Value);
        }
        else
        {
            Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pictext, txtpictext.Text);
        }

        Conn.Open();
        Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: So you know there is an *"inline c# if"*, but it's hard to use or what?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/1678311/993547, and many, many more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use the ternary operator ?:

```
Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pictext, string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtpictext.Text) 
  ? DBNull.Value 
  : txtpictext.Text);

Conn.Open();
Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Like so.

Answer (score 0):

```
string assignedValue = string.Empty;
assignedValue = string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtpictext.Text) ? DBNull.Value : txtpictext.Text ;
Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pictext", assignedValue);
Conn.Open();
Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```